# How to select specific value in sas

Tags: sql, sas

Suppose I have the data set like this:

```
value1    value2   value3
X1       X2       X3
Y1       Y2       Y3
Z1       Z2       Z3
```

I want to select out the Y1, Z1 and X2 to three new variables.

like this:

```
a1 = Y1
a2 = Z1
a3 = X2
```

---

In answer to Reese, this is what I want following the idea of yours

```
%macro coeff(i=, j=, k=);
data want_&k.;
set new;
array va(3) value1 value2 value3;

%if &i.=1 %then %do;
        va(_n_)=va(_n_+&j.);
%end;

%else %if &i.=2 %then %do;
        va(_n_)=va(_n_+&j.);
%end;

keep value1;
run;
%mend;

%coeff(i=1, j=1, k=1);
%coeff(i=1, j=2, k=2);
%coeff(i=2, j=1, k=3);
%coeff(i=2, j=1, k=4);
%coeff(i=3, j=-2, k=5);
%coeff(i=3, j=-1, k=6);
```

But it doesn't work. Can you take a look?

Comment: you want to update the current values in Value1 column with the new values that you posted?

Comment: I really wish you'd take the time to explain this problem more thoroughly.  The logic does not make sense and the reason for doing this may not make sense either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answers your first question, but I have a feeling its not what you're actually after. 
I've also added in a second dataset have2, perhaps you can better explain what you're after if the data is in that structure.

```
data have;
input value1 $    value2 $  value3 $;
cards;
X1       X2       X3
Y1       Y2       Y3
Z1       Z2       Z3
;
run;

data want;
set have;
array va(3) value1-value3;

if _n_=1 then va(_n_)=va(_n_+1);

keep value1;
run;


data have2;
    set have;
    array va(3) value1-value3;

    do i=1 to 3;
        value=va(i);
        row=_n_;
        output;
    end;
    keep value row;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks! data set want 2 is exactly what I want. Can you write them in a macro that generate all the six possible combinations?

Comment: @Lu Yu - I moved your attempted edit to your own post. If you need to ask further questions that are too large to ask as a comment, editing your own post is better than editing the answer that someone else gave.

Answer (score 0):

This still makes absolutely no sense to me, context would help.

```
data have;
input value1 $    value2 $  value3 $;
cards;
X1       X2       X3
Y1       Y2       Y3
Z1       Z2       Z3
;
run;

data have2;
    set have end=eof;
    array va(3) value1-value3;
    retain counter 2;
    do i=1 to 3;
        value=va(i);
        row=_n_;
        if eof and i=3 then counter=1;
        output;
        counter+1;
    end;
    keep value counter;
run;

proc sort data=have2;
by counter;
run;

data have3;
    set have2;
    retain counter2 0;
    if mod(counter,3)=1 then counter2+1;
    drop counter i row;
run;

data _null_;
    set have3;
    by counter2;
    name=cats("a",counter2);
    if first.counter2 then do;
        call execute ("data " || name || "; set have3; where counter2=" ||counter2|| ";run;");
    end;
run;
```